# QGIS: Info window about every layer is not readable

Tags: qgis, layers, infowindow, linux-mint

I have a new problem in QGIS 3.28.8 (OS Linux Mint 21.2):
If I move the mouse over a layer-name in the layer panel on the left, usually I can read some information about this layer (data source, active filters, coordinate system etc.) in a small window.

In my case it does not work any more.I see a small window, but I cannot read any text in it.

I am not sure since when this mistakes occurs. Some days ago I changed my operating system from Linux Mint 21.1 to 21.2.

When I open in the QGIS-Project settings - options - general I can choose between different styles (in my case default is "Fusion"). Fusion, plastique, motif, Windows make this mistake, only Qt5ct and gtk2 show readable windows in the descripted situation. But these styles do not fit because of other reasons.

Has anybody an idea how I can get back the readable small windows?

Answer (score 0):

Now I could find the reason for the problem. By upgrading the OS LinuxMint 21.1 to 21.2 the OS changed many system themes (Layout), and the automatically adopted theme (Mint-Y) does not fit to QGIS. So I had to change the theme (f.e. Mint-L or High Contrast) and QGIS works fine again (and the info windows are readable again).